# Long delay to login on a locally hosted DB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication, .net-core

so I'm creating a little WinForms project for uni and i created an event handler to handle the login logic which you can find below but it takes about 370-450 ms to authenticate the user  which i think but I'm not sure is a little too long considering that the database is localy hosted

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            


            string email = EmailText.Text;
            string password = PasswordText.Text;

                using (var db = new CRMContext())
                {
                    var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

                    if (user != null && BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, user.PasswordHash))
                    {
         
                    // Authentication successful
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Login time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                    this.Hide();
                        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
                        mainForm.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Authentication failed
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid email or password.");
                    }
                }

            }
```

I haven't tried anything honestly it's my first time doing any sort of authentication logic

Comment: It normal for authentication to take some time.  Code has to go a server to verify the password and it take time to perform the query over the network.

Comment: Cryptographic hashes are [deliberately slow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150620/). Making them faster makes them much easier to crack.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the Work factor does-I've read somewhere that it affects the bruteforceability of the hash-  but even setting it to it's lowest value (4) didn't matter

Comment: What is taking a long time, pulling the hash or verifying it? Note that this setup is not very secure, as a user can easily pull the hash straight off the database.

Comment: I honestly don't know , how would i know which one is taking longer ? also it's just a college project so security isn't that important i mean if i would save the the password as just plain text the prof wouldn't even know or care (yes he's that bad ) but i've read somewhere that i can save the hash and salt in two different tables or something like that I'm assuming that's more secure but i honestly just wanna get this project done asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, and probably the simplest thing, is to make sure the Email column in the DB is indexed, it'll speed up queries that filter the email column.

Secondly, if the password hashes are too long it can slow down the process.. you can try reducing the cost factor by generating shorter hashes (though I wouldn't really recommend it, can impose security issues):

```
BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(10))
```

If you're frequently requesting from the database, Connection Pooling might be something worth looking into... it just allows you to reuse database connections though that's usually better across networks rather than locally.

And besides caching, you could try making it asynchronous? It'll allow you to free up the UI thread while waiting for the DB query to finish which is more of a QOL thing:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    
    string email = EmailText.Text;
    string password = PasswordText.Text;

    using (var db = new CRMContext())
    {
        var user = await db.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email);

        if (user != null && BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, user.PasswordHash))
        {
            // Authentication successful
            stopwatch.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Login time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
            this.Hide();
            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
            mainForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // Authentication failed
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid email or password.");
        }
    }
}
```

The authentication process is generally "lengthy", you'd much rather have security over fast speeds 99% of the time. <1sec response times is still great and should have minimal user impact most of the time

Comment: not gonna lie i didn't know about DB indexing and Pooling but after looking them I'll definitely use them in this project and future ones